# API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key, как исправить?

Tags: oauth, google-cloud

Использую google cloud speech to text api в gcp. Создал сервисный аккаунт, OAuth 2.0 client IDs, API key. OAuth consent screen просто создал добавил свое api в scope, сохранял без верификации. Шел по этому мануалу https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-speech-intro/index.html#6

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary 
@request.json "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize? 
key=${AIzaSyA0An23P-f9RdlovXeu4EVsgjj_CMTuImU}"
```

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "API key not valid. Please pass a valid API key.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
        "links": [
          {
            "description": "Google developers console",
            "url": "https://console.developers.google.com"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос? ))) Не правильный же API key. Вы его по инструкции получили? Пробовали сгенерировать новый?

Comment: Делал по инструкции конечно же)) сгенерировать новый, даже проект пересоздавал. Вопрос, пофиксить эту ошибку?)

Comment: поправил ответ. Причина: ключ не надо оборачивать в `${}`. И тело запроса нужно указать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Неверный запрос. Нужно так:

```
curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data-binary '{"config":{"encoding":"FLAC","languageCode":"en-US"}, "audio":{"uri":"gs://cloud-samples-tests/speech/brooklyn.flac"}}' "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize?key=AIzaSyA0An23P-f9RdlovXeu4EVsgjj_CMTuImU"
```

Ответ:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "how old is the Brooklyn Bridge",
          "confidence": 0.98314303
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```